# pop!_os with realtek ALC711-CG sound card, no audio device

Tags: drivers, audio, realtek, pop-os

I recently install pop!_os on a dell latitude 9420.

I'm loving it so far, except, I wasn't able to play audio at all on it.

the laptop comes with a realtek ALC711-CG, which I've read causes a lot of audio issues I have read.

From the system settings only the dummy output peripheral is listed.

So, far I tried following many different guides: including the audio troubleshooting in the system76 website.

1. restarting pulseaudio and removing it's config files.
2. adding the snd_hda_intel kernel module in the alsa conf in the modprobe.d folder and blacklisting the snd_soc_skl
3. I tried a different guide that makes you install sof-firmware and the soundwire configurations
4. I tried using a solution that was listed to solve the problem build and installing the soundwire dkms but it couldn't build cause it was intended for <=5.9 linux kernel.

uname -a

```
Linux aries 5.11.0-7620-generic #21~1624379747~21.04~3abeff8-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 23 02:34:03 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -v | grep -A6 Audio

```
    0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 222
    Memory at 607a2d8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 607a000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

aplay -l

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord -l

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
```

I can't really seem to get the system to correctly detect and use the device.

I really need some help :D

Comment: Did you try other distros? Or newer kernels?

Comment: now I am running:

Linux aries 5.15.5-76051505-generic #202111250933~1638201579~21.04~09f1aa7-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 30 02: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and it got fixed roughly around the end of october, it's still suboptimal cause i have to reload the audio configuration from time to time and the quality isn't where it should be, but it kinda works, it's just scuffed